# google chrome pdf viewer using p:media

Tags: pdf, primefaces

i have this code snippit:

```
<p:media value="#{testController.simplePDF()}" player="pdf" width="300px" height="300px">  
    No PDF file uploaded.
</p:media>
```

simplePDF method returns `simplePDF = new DefaultStreamedContent(is, "application/pdf");`

sometimes the method returns null if no pdf has been found in the database. but when it returns null it should display "No PDF File uploaded."

This works in firefox, the problem is in chrome. it displays a message below the chrome url saying "Could not load PDF viewer" and it displays me a "couldn't load plug in" with a broken plug in image. I need it to display it as "No PDF file uploaded."

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

- Go to Chrome's navigator bar and in: chrome://plugins/
- Deactivate the PDF Viewer
- Run your app again and you should see the PDF